# Being "open relative to D" where $D$ is a set - problem with the book's way of looking

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So when proving a theorem, my book used to following statement in the proof :

> Let $F(X))= A \cup B$ where A and B are mutually separated, F is a continuous function defined on the set $X$ Since A
>   and B have no arbitrary close points to each other, A, B are open
>   related to $F(X)$

I couldn't understand how it derived this from the definition of being open related to .

Set $X$ is open related to set $Y$ if it is $X=A \cap Y$ where $A$ is an open set.

Anyway, consider this

Let $f(p)$ be a function defined on a set S, Assume $f$ takes only values $2$ and $3$. 
Okay so we can say $F(S)= N \cup M$ where $N=2$ and $M=3$

This contradicts with the book's way of looking at things, it seems pretty obvious tome that both $N$ and $M$ are closed sets.

Comment: What is $F$? If function, what are the properties of $F$? Also, what is the meaning of close points to each other?

Comment: @user64066 that they are a distance apart

Comment: May I ask which book is this?

Comment: @user64066 Advanced calculus by buck

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the proof for image of a connected set under continuous map is also connected. In that case, the theorem is true when $X$ is connected, so your example fails because the set is not connected.

If you want to prove

> $F(X)$ is connected when  $F$ is continuous on connected set $X$.

here is the outline: Suppose not. So $F(X)= A\cup B$ where $A,B$ nonempty and separated sets. Put $G=X\cap f^{-1} (A)$ and $H=X\cap f^{-1}(B)$. It is easy to show that $G\cap H=\emptyset$ and $G$ and $H$ are separated. This contradicts with connectedness of $X$ and the result follows.

Comment: What makes , A , B open related to f(X)  if X is connected